# SSL handshake failure with soap adapter

Tags: java, ssl, soap, jetty

We have a Third party application which has a soap adapter build with Jetty 6.1. The application gets an inbound request from a .Net application through the SOAP adapter, through SSL.

Recently the SSL certificate expired and the security team has added a new certificate to the truststore.

The problem is that Jetty gets list of all the certificates but only uses first one (expired) and the handshake fails.

Following are some snippets of logs. Few lines have been marked as xxxxxxxxx to hide text.

This shows 3 alias, the first one is expired on 8th Oct 2017.

```
JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest MD5 from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest SHA from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain RSA
matching alias: 44240-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-org
matching alias: 111824-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-org
matching alias: 109491-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-org
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, chooseEngineServerAlias 44240-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-org
ssl: ServerHandshaker.setupPrivateKeyAndChain, return true

**%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1491745993 bytes = { 73, 37, 191, 131, 31, 235, 131, 242, 96, 119, 124, 73, 57, 221, 38, 112, 19, 216, 144, 221, 184, 25, 181, 210, 229, 39, 62, 50 }
Session ID:  {89, 234, 61, 201, 31, 215, 166, 2, 132, 100, 188, 234, 63, 57, 167, 114, 199, 190, 119, 228, 154, 176, 153, 236, 115, 222, 35, 98, 53, 182, 88, 140}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, ri_length: 0, ri_connection_data: { null }
***
Cipher suite:  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx.org, OU=TreSOAP Server Test-PROD Primary, O=XXXX-XXXXX - internal dmz, L=Saint Louis, ST=Missouri, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  IBMPKCS11Impl RSA Public Key: 
 Token: false
 Private: false
 Label: IBMPKCS1162112826090763885165327
 Modifiable: true
 KeyType: 0
 ID: 
 Start Date: Wed Dec 31 17:59:59 CST 1969
 End Date: Wed Dec 31 17:59:59 CST 1969
 Derive: false
 Local: false
 Subject: 
 Encrypt: true
 Verify: true
 VerifyRecover: true
 Wrap: true
 modulus: 26606850225087850589932908027067524318268268224826270839465320725092268136382373728617246685378243753417909514269416692823470338958771068354701078301334195882971493513282715502700026787422539437203244486983379743077668035555448903482759728453372918271687510462097996374206565621965829077017536736170426765991639165149047482746818974654077122772442139310513169191565788646178636478714837968871155118100289147723685748486274263964655017819372517057114974155848311538134591086912352063631149931407513232621741060410510212626457131410022996185588768438731050436344397255226489472133617477053078911021189068729861786067773
 modulus bits: 2048
 public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Wed Oct 09 12:59:36 CDT 2013,
               To: Sun Oct 08 12:49:19 CDT 2017]
  Issuer: CN=MC Internal Zone Applications sub CA, OU=Global Information Security, O=XXXX, DC=xxxx, DC=com
  SerialNumber: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

Certificate Extensions: 6
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: cf 53 c3 63 61 83 f7 cd  4c 99 6a af 72 16 63 ee  .S.ca...L.j.r.c.
0010: 63 48 23 2c                                        cH..
]

[CN=Internal Zone Applications root CA, OU=Global Information Security, O=XXXX XXXX, DC=xxxx, DC=com]
SerialNumber: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
CA:false
PathLen: undefined
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtKeyUsage [
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1   1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.16.840.1.113730.1.1 Criticality=false
NetscapeCertType [
   SSL client
   SSL server
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 8b 74 8c b4 9e 21 d6 dd  86 f0 51 5f 77 c0 21 52  .t........Q.w..R
0010: 78 ab a8 2a                                        x...
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

]
***
*** ServerHelloDone
301601274@qtp-1542806517-9, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1443
301601274@qtp-1542806517-9, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
301601274@qtp-1542806517-9, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
301601274@qtp-1542806517-9, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
301601274@qtp-1542806517-9, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**
```

Need help from experts to figure out what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be with the SslSelectChannelConnector which was overridden in the application to support HSM, however the jetty version was updated and the changes to support the new version of jetty was not incorporated in the Overridden class.